# Why we need to have a current output on power supply to drive some devices (such as curve tracer)?

Tags: power-supply, current

Last week, I just had an experiment on lab, in which I need to use a transistor curve tracer board and thus was asked to connect it to a digital supply.

I connected them and sat voltage output of power supply as 12 V (as said in my lab note) and 0A. However, the tracer did not work correctly. I asked my mentor and he said I need to set a current output like 1 mA to supply enough supply, which finally worked.

My question is, why we need a current output on power supply or why it won't have a current output automatically? I do understand that if the power supply has 0 A current, based on P = UI, there is no 0 W of power supply. However, if I connect a 12V and 0A power supply to a 1k ohms, it will have a 12 mA current on the circuit, which means the power supply provide current "automatically"?

Comment: If you limit the powersupply to 0A, no current will flow.

Comment: IU=P guess why it is called "power" supply and "powering" devices

Comment: Thank you so much JRE and PlasmaHH. I'm so sorry of having no idea how to reply the comment in StackExchange as I'm new to here. But many thanks for you guys' reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention a **current output** but that's not entirely correct. You are probably talking about a **current limit setting**.

That means the following, say we set the supply to 12 V, 10 mA:

- As long as no more than 10 mA is supplied to the load, the voltage will be 12 V. The supply will work in **constant voltage mode** often shorted as CV.
- If you connect a load that wants to make more than 10 mA flow at 12 V, the supply will **lower the voltage** such that 10 mA flows. It will be in **current limiting mode** or **constant current mode** often shorted as CC.
- In case you use a resistor as load we can use Ohm's law to find the resistor where the change between CV and CC happens: 12 V/10mA = 1.2 kohm, so a resistor with a value of more than 1.2 kohm will result in a current of less than 10 mA so it will get 12 V (CV). A resistor with a value below 1.2 kohm will want to make more than 10 mA flow at 12 V, the supply does not allow this and will reduce the voltage such that no more than 10 mA flows (CC).

> However, if I connect a 12V and 0A power supply to a 1k ohms, it will have a 12 mA current on the circuit

No, that is not correct, if you set the current to 0 A so **no current will flow**.
To make the 12 mA you have to set the current limit setting to **at least** 12 mA.

Comment: +1. You can use the `>` markup for quotations. Don't leave a space after the `>`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just checked the datasheet of power supply we used and also searched the concept of current limit of power supply. I have misunderstood the function of current indicator of power supply as providing that value of current, which indeed should be current limit. Again thank you so much for the answer and details.